# Parsear JSON con Laravel

Tags: laravel, json, guzzle

Estoy intentando parsear un JSON pero no logro cargar los datos que necesito...

Tengo el siguiente json, que me da los datos de varios clientes:

```json
{
   "totaldocuments": 30535,
   "totaldocumentslocated": 30535,
   "advertisements": [
      {
         "basicinfo": {
            "name": "ACA NOMBRE",
            "urls": {
               "web": "web1",
               "webgenerica": "web2",
               "urlficha": "web3"
            },
```

En mi laravel tengo:

```
$url= 'url.json';

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['auth' => ['admin', 'password'],]);
$res = $client->get($url);
$content = (string) $res->getBody();
    
$clientes = json_decode($content, true);

$basicinfo = $clientes['advertisements'][0]['basicinfo'];

return view('test::leads', ['basicinfo'=> $basicinfo]);
```

En mi blade tengo:

```
@foreach ($basicinfo as $info)

  {{$info['name']}} <br>
        
@endforeach
```

El error que aparece es:
`Cannot access offset of type string on string`

Hice varios intentos y solo logro ingresar al primero por ejemplo, totaldocuments... con:

```php
return $clientes['totaldocuments']
```

Me retorna 30535 sin problemas.

¿Alguien me puede dar una mano con esto por favor?

Desde ya muchisimas gracias.

Edito:

```
$clientes = json_decode($content, true);
$basicinfo = $clientes['advertisements'];
return view('test::leads', ['clientes'=> $clientes]);
```

así pude recorrer el interior.

```
@foreach ($clientes['advertisements'] as $key => $lead)
        {{$lead['basicinfo']['name']}}
@endforeach
```

Ahora estoy intentando recorrer los interiores de esos como ser el caso de URL

Comment: En el JSON, en el apartado "basicinfo", cuantos elementos tiene? uno solo como en el ejemplo?

Comment: Hola, no, tiene varios... tiene, name, address, cirty, urls que en ese caso, urls dentro tiene a su vez, web, webgenerica, urlficha... vale aclarar que urls esta dentro de basicinfo.. fuera de basicinfo tengo infoplus osea al mismo nivel que basicinfo tengo otro que es infoplus... pero con resolver lo de arriba me arreglo con el resto

Comment: Veo que has editado la pregunta, entiendo que has conseguido arreglarlo?

Comment: Si, lo que no logro recorrer es dentro de urls... el resto pude solucionar todo

Comment: De acuerdo, siempre existira un elemento URL? y siempre sera tipo array? aunque este vacio?

Comment: Si y en caso de no existir lo estoy solucionando con un ?? ''. pero en caso de existir si, será tal cual el ejemplo

Comment: Te lo escribo como respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Prueba lo de las url con esto

```php
@foreach ($clientes['advertisements'] as $key => $lead)
    {{$lead['basicinfo']['name']}}
    @foreach ($lead['basicinfo']['urls'] as $key => $url)
        {{$key}} -> {{$url}}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: No, mira estoy haciendolo por controller ahora como para guardar la db y despues generar un json un poco mas simple para la vista...

Aquí si pude entrar a urls pero el foreach solo me almacena el ultimo dato...

foreach ($item['basicinfo']['urls'] as $key => $url){
                $asd['web'] = $url;
              }

En las que tiene solamente web me almacena web.. si tiene web y web generica... me guarda solo la web generica y si tiene las 3 me guarda urlficha... es rarisimo

Comment: @KatiaSisHost no he entendido nada... de todas formas de donde sale ```$asd['web']```??? si tu estas creando una vaariable llamada ```$url```

Comment: $asd['web'] es para almacenar en la db